# Grab link from page and scroll to anchor on main page

Tags: jquery, url, window, anchor

I have multiple links on my main page that each has an id. On the linked pages I have a link (.myClose) that goes back to the main page (index). Before it executes I grab the window href and want to scroll to that anchor when returning to the main page, so far I've got:

Main page:

```
<a href="portfolio/1/" id="1">
<a href="portfolio/2/" id="2">
<a href="portfolio/3/" id="3">
```

Portfolio pages (pageIndex equals the page number):

```
$('.myClose').click(function(event) {
        var href = this.href;
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location = href+pageIndex;
});
```

Back to main page (window url becomes http://page#1) but it doesn't scroll to #1:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    var toHash = window.location.href;
    window.location = toHash;
    $('html,body,#wrap').animate({scrollTop:(toHash).offset().top}, 500);
});
```

Comment: You're missing the `$` on the jQuery object: `scrollTop: $(toHash).offset().top`. Also, `window.location = toHash;` can be removed.

Comment: Thanks, seems like the issue is that the scroll wasn't working because the link id's have hidden visibility (using ScrollReveal). In that case how can I scroll to them if they are currently invisible in the viewport? the div containing them already has the height set, you just scroll to make them appear.

Comment: Seems like another scrolling plugin was causing the issue, it works fine now. Feel free to add an answer so I can select it @RoryMcCrossan